# Angular 13: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Tags: angular, typescript, export, syntax-error, angular13

I have updated the Angular from 12 to 13. When I run the app I am getting the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export". Adding below few details to get the context.

In angular.json config, I had below entry in scripts section.

"./node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/**core.umd.js**"

After the angular update to 13, I noticed that in place of umd JS files we have .mjs file
"./node_modules/@angular/core/**esm2020**/**core.mjs**".

**Note:**
Error is from scripts.js and it's pointing to the line "export * from './index';" (this line is from **core.mjs** file)

Please let me know if anybody has faced this issue and solution for the same?

I tried adding the type "module" in main package.json. But still getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @deepak can you try to use a supported Node.JS version? (10, 12 or 14)

Node.JS version 13 is no longer supported by the Node.JS team. If you are using nodejs > 14 please share your package.json info

Comment: Hi, I am using the node v12.20.2.

Comment: Hi, Do you have deleted node_modules folder and re installed it?

Comment: Yes, I tried that as well.. Still facing the same issue